# Convert varchar column with values 000000 to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have varchar column in that the values like 
100715 
000000 
000000
Etc.

These are in mmddyy format. I want this to convert to datetime. My final table column is datetime datatype.  Please let me know.

Comment: What is the format? Something like `MMddyy HHmmss ffffff` where the `ffffff` is the number of microseconds after the whole number of seconds? Or do some of the zeroes signify a time zone offset?

Comment: @ Jeppe Stig -- 000000 is in format mmddyy. In my column i have values 100715 as one row and 000000 as another row.

Comment: Then what is month `00`, and day `00`? The month is in the interval `01` through `12`, and the day `01` through `31`. Do you want `1900/01/01` or `NULL` or something when the varchar is `'000000'`?

Answer (score 1):

Code:
**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c24d7/7)**

```
SELECT convert(datetime, substring(dt,5,2)+substring(dt,1,2)+substring(dt,3,2), 12)
```

Result:

```
|                        dt |
|---------------------------|
| October, 07 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? ...

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, ColumnName)

CONVERT(DATETIME, 'SomeVarcharValueHere')
```

Comment: Tried all possible combinations using cast ,convert, stuff but could not get.

Comment: @prasad , you cannot be able to do that .. what do you want is `datetime`, and datetime column will have output something like `2010-07-15 00:00:00.000` , the only thing you can do if you want the `mmddyy` format is to convert your output into `varchar`

Comment: (to latest comment) His format seems to imply October 07, 2015 followed by a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: @Odedra , it is not hard to understand , it is only conversion into `datetime` which even student can understand.. im just trying to help base on the OP, no need so much comment as i put it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(000000 AS DATETIME) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem